# race-condition: reading/writing file (windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x, race-condition, file-locking

I have the following situation:

-different users (all on windows OS) that run a python script that can either read or write to pickle file located on a shared folder.

-the "system" is designed in way that only one user at a time will be writing to the file (therefore no race condition of more processes trying to WRITE at the same time on the file)

-the basic code to write would be this:

```
with open(path + r'\final_db.p', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump((x, y), f)
```

-while code to read would be:

```
with open(path + r'\final_db.p', 'rb') as f:
    x, y = pickle.load(f)
```

-x is list of 5K or plus elements, where each element is a class instance containing many attributes and functions; y is a date

QUESTION:

am i correct assuming that there is a race condition when a reading and a writing process overlap? and that the reading one can end up with a corrupt file?

PROPOSED SOLUTIONS:

1.a possible solution i thought of is using filelock:

code to write:

```
file_path = path + r'\final_db.p'
lock_path = file_path + '.lock'
lock = filelock.FileLock(lock_path, timeout=-1)
with lock:
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump((x, y), f)
```

code to read:

```
file_path = path + r'\final_db.p'
lock_path = file_path + '.lock'
lock = filelock.FileLock(lock_path, timeout=-1)
with lock:
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
         x, y = pickle.load(f)
```

this solution should work (??), but if a process crash, the file remains blocked till the "file_path + '.lock'" is cancelled

2.another solution could be to use portalocker

code to write:

```
with open(path + r'\final_db.p', 'wb') as f:
    portalocker.lock(f, portalocker.LOCK_EX)
    pickle.dump((x, y), f)
```

code to read:

```
segnale = True
while segnale:
    try:
        with open(path + r'\final_db.p', 'rb') as f:
            x, y = pickle.load(f)
        segnale = False
    except:
        pass
```

the reading process, if another process started writing before it, will keep looping till the file is unlocked (except PermissionError).
if the writing process started after the reading process, the reading should loop if the file is corrupt.
what i am not sure about is if the reading process could end up reading a partially written file.

Any advice? better solutions?